# column setting "Require that this column contains information " will be set to No when creating a list

Tags: 2013, list, content-type, column, site-column

I am working on SP 2013 + team site collection. I have the following scenario which I can not understand:

1 - I have created a custom site column named `“Area”` of type drop down list with choices and I set the Area column as `"Require that this column contains information" = Yes`  inside the column definition:

[image]

2 -  And I added the site column inside a custom site content type, and I set it as required:

[image]

Now inside my sub site I created a new issue tracking list and I changed its default content type from Issue to be the above custom content type. Then I remove the Issue content type from the list.

Now when I checked the Area column inside my list columns, I found that the Area has the `“Require that this column contains information:” set to NO`  , although at the site level it is set to Yes  . and to set it as Yes (as defined inside the site column)  I had to to edit the site column Area  and choose to updated the underlying columns to get it defined as Required again inside the list columns.while inside the list content type the Area is still defined a Required which is good.

So can anyone advise why SP set the Area site column as `“Require that this column contains information:” = NO`   inside the list , while it is defined as `"Require that this column contains information" = Yes` inside the site columns ?

Comment: in Sharepoint Online I followed all the path you decribed above and in list "Require that this column contains information" property is not shown when edit in list. Also when i try to add new item it looks required. Everything looks ok for me.

Comment: @Yavuz but i am not using SP online i am using on-primise SP with SP1..